# Почему switch/case выводит не заданное выражение?

Tags: php

Надо вывести значение `post_max_size`, которое указано в настройках *PHP*

Есть такой код:

```
$size = ini_get("post_max_size");
$letter = $size{strlen($size)-1};
$size = (int)$size;

switch($letter){
    case 'G':
        $size *= 1024;
    case 'M':
        $size *= 1024;
    case 'K':
        $size *= 1024;
}
echo $size;
```

Зачем умножать мегабайты, если потом выведет, совсем не то число?

Это по урокам специалиста, но как работает этот код, он не показал и перешёл к другой теме.
Может просто, быстро показал для примера?

Comment: он должен выдать количество килобайт в мегабайте например 4 мегабайт будет равно 4 * 1024 килобайт

Comment: @L.Vadim в байтах он выведет без брейков

Answer (score 3):

Вообще тут показывается работа оператора `switch` и, в частности, что будет, если не писать `break` в конце каждого `case`. Ибо по дефолтку, попадая в одну из веток `case`, если не писать `break`, то код будет "проваливаться" вниз и выполнять остальные ветки, игнорируя нижележащие инструкции. В этом суть данного примера (и, кстати, на сколько я помню, я видел урок и там как раз вполне всё объясняется от начала работы оператора и до задачи с информацией из файла..........**UPD**: я даже нашел **[Видео](https://youtu.be/Vsj7UgXNti4?t=187)** - начиная с 3 минуты и до 30... разжёвано подробнейше).

Поэтому если, например, `$letter == 'G'`, то значение `size` умножится на 1024, потом провалится вниз к `M` (но буква уже не будет с ним сравниваться, а сразу исполнится инструкция), еще раз умножится, провалится к `K` (тоже сравниваться буква уже не будет) и умножится еще раз. В общем, **итог** показа будет отображение данных **в байтах**. Если такое поведение не нужно — ставятся "бряки".